# Cannot scroll to view by id (smoothly) - HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have this click anchor-tag `<a>`:

```
        <a href="#" onclick="ScrollToView()">Who we are</a>
```

and I have this **div** later in the HTML:

```
<div id="whoweare" align="center" class="box-2">
                <div align="center> 
                    <font color="#534f4f" size="+1">    
                        <h1>Who we are</h1>
                    </font>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px">   
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr> <!--tablerow-->
                            <th width=400px>
                                <div align="center">    
                                    <img 
                                        src="./img/me.png"
                                        width=60%
                                    </img>  
                                </div>
                            </th>   
                            <td width=400px>
                                <div align="justify">   
                                    <font color="#534f4f" size="+2" >   
                                        <h3>Julius Tolksdorf</h3>
                                        <p>CEO of innomotion media and head of software development.<br>
                                            He will be your primary contact during the planning and development processes.
                                            Julius has already finished about 20 apps & games & web pages and has years of experience being an Android & Unity developer.
                                        </p> 
                                    </font>
                                </div>
                            </td>   
                        </tr> <!--for padding-->
                            <tr height=20px/>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

attached is a js file with a function:

```
function ScrollToView()
{
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("whoweare");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView(false); 
}
```

But upon click, it is supposed to go where the id is "whoweare" but it just doesn't do anything at all (actually, it kind of "jumps" back to the beginning of the page, but of course that is not the intended behavior).

I know that my JS is attached correctly since I can fire other functions with this onclick method from the same script. So, it must be the function that isn't working right. Maybe I am doing it wrong?

### Edit

If I change my function up to look like this:

```
function ScrollToView(id) 
{
    var elmnt = document.getElementById(id);
    alert(elmnt);
    elmnt.scrollIntoView(true); 
}
```

the alert is just saying: "[object HTMLDivElement]"

But it doesn't seem to include the right tag. Or is this normal?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView
there is no full support for that feature... maybe that's the issue?

Comment: elmnt.scrollIntoView - try without false, just with empty brackets

Comment: I just provided my suggestion in answer

Answer (score 2):

To scroll o the top of the page use *true* parameter:

```
function ScrollToView() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("whoweare");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView(true); 
}
```

See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)...

Comment: Check https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView if that feature is supported by the browser you use, as @YAMM suggested...

Comment: And also please open Developer Tools (`F12` on Chrome and Mozilla) to check if you happen to have any errors in your js code which is not shown in the question...

Comment: On this fiddle it looks like it is working... (https://jsfiddle.net/marcolino/dcmnzfvw/9/)

Comment: Possibly you are expecting a behaviour different from the specs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your code vanilla js you can try:

```
function ScrollToView()
{
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("whoweare");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView(); 
}
```

If you also use jQuery you can use this version instead:

```
$("#whoweare").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#whoweare").offset().top // You can change #whoweare to the id where you want to scroll to
    }, 2000);
});
```

I find it more useful because you can scroll to any id of the page and you can also decide speed tweaking the number.

Comment: hello. the first one is what i already did many times and there is no result. the second one is new to me. how would i implement that?

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your page? If yes you can just paste the code in the bottom of your html for testing.
Before closing the body add a script tag and put the code in it (good enough for testing).

Comment: have never used jQ before. How do i get my a href to call this function?

Comment: okay i just used it too, but there is no scrolling happening... could this be related to me using the newest firefox? or bc everything is stored locally?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: no. well only something about not defining the ascii thingy but that should be an issue, right? xD

Comment: If you get a javascript error then your code is quite likely not completely executed.
Just put somewhere in your javascript alert("I am working"); and you will find out quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll seems working if you can can use JQuery with a button. Checkout this code
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEWQgm

```
<button>Click to Bottom</button>
<div align="center" class="box-2">
    <div align="center> 

                    <font color=" #534f4f " size=" +1 ">    
                        <h1>Who we are</h1>
                    </font>
                </div>
                <div style=" padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px ">   
                    <table border=" 0 ">
                        <tr> <!--tablerow-->
                            <th width=400px>
                                <div align=" center ">    
                                    <img 
                                        src=" ./img/me.png "
                                        width=60%
                                    </img>  
                                </div>
                            </th>   
                            <td width=400px>
                                <div align=" justify ">   
                                    <font color=" #534f4f " size=" +2 " >   
                                        <h3>Julius Tolksdorf</h3> 
                                        <p>CEO of innomotion media and head of software development.<br>
                                            He will be your primary contact during the planning and development processes.
                                            Julius has already finished about 20 apps & games & web pages and has years of experience being an Android & Unity developer.
                                        </p> 
                                    </font>
                                </div>
                            </td>   
                        </tr> <!--for padding-->
                            <tr height=20px/>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
        <div align="center" class="box-2">
    <div align="center> 

                    <font color=" #534f4f " size=" +1 ">    
                        <h1>Who we are</h1>
                    </font>
                </div>
                <div style=" padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px ">   
                    <table border=" 0 ">
                        <tr> <!--tablerow-->
                            <th width=400px>
                                <div align=" center ">    
                                    <img 
                                        src=" ./img/me.png "
                                        width=60%
                                    </img>  
                                </div>
                            </th>   
                            <td width=400px>
                                <div align=" justify ">   
                                    <font color=" #534f4f " size=" +2 " >   
                                        <h3>Julius Tolksdorf</h3> 
                                        <p>CEO of innomotion media and head of software development.<br>
                                            He will be your primary contact during the planning and development processes.
                                            Julius has already finished about 20 apps & games & web pages and has years of experience being an Android & Unity developer.
                                        </p> 
                                    </font>
                                </div>
                            </td>   
                        </tr> <!--for padding-->
                            <tr height=20px/>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
        <div align="center" class="box-2">
    <div align="center> 

                    <font color=" #534f4f " size=" +1 ">    
                        <h1>Who we are</h1>
                    </font>
                </div>
                <div style=" padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px ">   
                    <table border=" 0 ">
                        <tr> <!--tablerow-->
                            <th width=400px>
                                <div align=" center ">    
                                    <img 
                                        src=" ./img/me.png "
                                        width=60%
                                    </img>  
                                </div>
                            </th>   
                            <td width=400px>
                                <div align=" justify ">   
                                    <font color=" #534f4f " size=" +2 " >   
                                        <h3>Julius Tolksdorf</h3> 
                                        <p>CEO of innomotion media and head of software development.<br>
                                            He will be your primary contact during the planning and development processes.
                                            Julius has already finished about 20 apps & games & web pages and has years of experience being an Android & Unity developer.
                                        </p> 
                                    </font>
                                </div>
                            </td>   
                        </tr> <!--for padding-->
                            <tr height=20px/>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>

<div align="center" class="box-2">
    <div align="center> 

                    <font color=" #534f4f " size=" +1 ">    
                        <h1>Who we are</h1>
                    </font>
                </div>
                <div style=" padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px ">   
                    <table border=" 0 ">
                        <tr> <!--tablerow-->
                            <th width=400px>
                                <div align=" center ">    
                                    <img 
                                        src=" ./img/me.png "
                                        width=60%
                                    </img>  
                                </div>
                            </th>   
                            <td width=400px>
                                <div align=" justify ">   
                                    <font color=" #534f4f " size=" +2 " >   
                                        <h3>Julius Tolksdorf</h3> 
                                        <p>CEO of innomotion media and head of software development.<br>
                                            He will be your primary contact during the planning and development processes.
                                            Julius has already finished about 20 apps & games & web pages and has years of experience being an Android & Unity developer.
                                        </p> 
                                    </font>
                                </div>
                            </td>   
                        </tr> <!--for padding-->
                            <tr height=20px/>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>


<div id="whoweare" align=" center " class=" box-2 ">
<div align=" center>
        <font color="#534f4f" size="+1">
            <h1>Who we are</h1>
        </font>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <!--tablerow-->
                <th width=400px>
                    <div align="center">
                        <img src="./img/me.png" width=60% </img> </div> </th> <td width=400px>
                        <div align="justify">
                            <font color="#534f4f" size="+2">
                                <h3>Julius Tolksdorf</h3>
                                <p>CEO of innomotion media and head of software development.<br> He will be your primary
                                    contact during the planning and development processes. Julius has already finished
                                    about 20 apps & games & web pages and has years of experience being
                                    an Android & Unity developer.
                                </p>
                            </font>
                        </div>
                        </td>
            </tr>
            <!--for padding-->
            <tr height=20px />
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="" align="center" class="box-2">
        <div align="center> 
                    <font color=" #534f4f " size=" +1 ">    
                        <h1>Who we are</h1>
                    </font>
                </div>
                <div style=" padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px ">   
                    <table border=" 0 ">
                        <tr> <!--tablerow-->
                            <th width=400px>
                                <div align=" center ">    
                                    <img 
                                        src=" ./img/me.png "
                                        width=60%
                                    </img>  
                                </div>
                            </th>   
                            <td width=400px>
                                <div align=" justify ">   
                                    <font color=" #534f4f " size=" +2 " >   
                                        <h3>Julius Tolksdorf</h3>
                                        <p>CEO of innomotion media and head of software development.<br>
                                            He will be your primary contact during the planning and development processes.
                                            Julius has already finished about 20 apps & games & web pages and has years of experience being an Android & Unity developer.
                                        </p> 
                                    </font>
                                </div>
                            </td>   
                        </tr> <!--for padding-->
                            <tr height=20px/>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>

        <button>Click to Top</button>
```

This is the JavaScript, if you include jquery library up top in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#whoweare").offset().top - document.body.clientHeight + $(document).height()
}, 1000);
      });
});
```